# How can I profile time which program spends in sleep or IO operations

Tags: java, io, profiling

I know how to profile CPU/Memory. 
But now I need to profile some code which uses IO operations (`PlainSocketImpl.doConnect` and others) to understand which piece of code is taking most of the time.

Comment: You are looking for strict java monitoring or OS monitoring? If so which Os

Comment: I am looking for java monitoring solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has file and sockets probes that show you I/O data around the actual objects.

[image]

In the CPU views there is a thread selector that has a "Net I/O" state. If you select that state, you will only see times spent in I/O.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Answer (score 3):

On linux based systems you can try [iotop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/linux-iotop-simple-top-like-io-monitor/). Switch the view to show threads, then combine it with `jstack` outputs to match actual lines of code.

Not very automatic though.

Comment: +1 Right. The fraction of stack samples with sleep or I/O routines on the stack is the fraction of time spent doing those things.